# name of element mouse is hovering

Tags: jquery

I'm using a global variable that toggles between true and false on mouse enter of a div and then I'm using the value of this variable elsewhere to show / hide another element depending on the value.

Actually, another way to do what I want would be to know if the mouse is hovering a div called MyDiv. **I'm looking to remove the use of the global variable that toggles with the mouseenter/mouseleave events.**

I tried this:

```
 var test = $('#MyDiv').mouseover() ? 1 : 0;
```

but it's not working.

Let me know if you have a **1-liner** suggestion for returning the name of the div that's being hovered.

Thanks.

PS: I already know it can be done with more than 1 line

Comment: You want to know which element the mouse is currently over without having to add a hover handler to every element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store your flag in jQuery's data storage:

```
$(this).data("mouseover", true);
if ($(this).data("mouseover"))
```

Comment: This still stores some value; I was looking to see if jquery enabled you to determine the name of the div being hovered. Looks like it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('#MyDiv').mouseover(function(){
    //show/hide other div or any other code
}) ;
```

OR

you can set another global variable that tells you whether mouse is hovering on `MyDiv` like this:

```
$('#MyDiv').mouseover(function(){
    myDivHovering = true;
}).mouseout(function() {
    myDivHovering = false;
}) ;
```

Comment: The show/hide works within a SetTimeout; hence I need to know where the mouse is when the time comes, not when the mouse enters or leaves.

Comment: Right but I'm looking to make it work without a global variable (the functionality currently already works with a global variable). Any way to determine the name of the div being hovered?

Comment: You want to know when the SetTimeout fires, which element the mouse is hovering on? And you don't want a global variable? And what if  the mouse not hovering on a div at that point?

Comment: Yes, all that ! If the mouse isn't hovering the div then don't hide another div

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses a callback style to handle events. The functionality you're describing can be implemented like so:

```
var mouse_on_mydiv = false;
$('#MyDiv').hover(function onMouseIn() {
    mouse_on_mydiv = true;
    alert(this.id); // => 'MyDiv'
}, function onMouseOut() {
    mouse_on_mydiv = false;
});
```

Comment: yes, this is already what I have, using a global variable. I'm looking to remove the global variable.

Comment: I don't know the context here. What is stopping you from removing it? Is it being used in some other part of your code that you want to refactor?

Comment: The global variable is not being used anywhere else and everything works. It's just that I'm looking to remove the variable.

Comment: Sure, take it out then :) I'm not sure what you mean. Is it that you want to have a method like $('#MyDiv').isMouseOver() that you can call from elsewhere? In that case SLaks' answer would fit your requirements.